# Trying Google's 'Go' for Linux, and I could use some help

Tags: ubuntu, go

I'm new to Linux, so I'm trying Ubuntu; I've installed Google's Go, thought I might give it a try.

Though every-time I try to compile I get:
8g: Command not found

I'm confused.. Any help?

Comment: 1. How did you install Go?  2. What command are you running?

Comment: I followed this: ( http://golang.org/doc/install.html ) and the command is ( 8g hello.go ).

Comment: On Ubuntu it's now possible to just do sudo apt-get install golang

Answer (score 2):

This part of the installation process is partially discussed [here](http://golang.org/doc/install.html#environment).

You need to add what corresponds to your `$GOBIN` directory to your `$PATH`. Add the following line (adjusted for your system) to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH="$HOME/src/golang/bin:$PATH"
```

Keep in mind that while Go is heavily Unix-inspired, it's not representative of the "typical" Linux experience, which at present is a mix of Python and C.

Comment: `PATH=$GOBIN:$PATH` is a better choice.

Comment: @Mike Ramirez: Actually it's not: `GOBIN` is provided by `gomake`, which is in the bin directory. You're better off specifying the path to `gomake` (the one I've given), and letting it provide all the other environment variables when it executes.

Comment: I tend to set $GOBIN explicitly in my env and then add it to the PATH. gomake will use $GOROOT/bin by default, (which I set my GOBIN to). With PATH=$GOBIN:$PATH it's set and forget and only need to deal with GO* variables.

Answer (score 1):

Glancing through the guide you linked to, it doesn't appear to install 8g etc. to /usr/bin but rather to a directory in your home directory. Is the directory containing 8g in your path?

(If you're not sure how to test this, type `echo $PATH` in your terminal to get the current path list. If 8g wasn't in your path then try `export PATH=$PATH:/my/new/bit` and then try again. To make such a change permanent, you'll need to edit your `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: When I type ( echo $PATH) it does list home/tenrai/home/tenrai/go/bin

Comment: With no preceding forward slash?

Comment: Hmm, it might have had one; but now that I've started a new terminal and ran the echo again, it doesn't list it any more..

Comment: Well, `$PATH` is the list of directories that get searched when you try to run a program. What you need to do is amend it. I explained how in the answer above.

Comment: Okay, I think the export thing has worked; how can I edit it into the ~/.bashrc?

Comment: Can I just add it anywhere in the file?

Answer (score 0):

There are ubuntu packages for golang provided by Gustavo Niemeyer. Instructions for installing these packages are [here](http://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/browse_thread/thread/a378126d7d061f0e).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on amd64 machine then the compiler is 6g (and the linker is 6l).
You can find the type of the machine by running `uname -m`

Comment: It told me my compiler is 8g after it installed. But thank you.